# How to get field type of an object of Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\EntityField

Tags: views, 8

I want to filter the field type "links" out of my $handler:

```
/**
* Searches for the link field to use, if present.
*/
public function find_link_field() {
  foreach ($this->view->display_handler->getHandlers('field') as $id => $handler) {
    if($handler->fieldDefinition->type == 'link') { //-> protected properties!!
      return $id;
      break;
    }
}
```

As stated in the title, $handler is an object of type Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\EntityField. 
I'm writing a views plugin.
Also I implemented `use Drupal\views\FieldAPIHandlerTrait;`. But the method getFieldDefinition() is protected too!

Comment: Did you try with `$handler->fieldDefinition->getType()`  ?

Comment: Yes but no: 
"Error: Cannot access protected property Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\EntityField::$fieldDefinition... "

Comment: And `$handler->getFieldDefinition()->getType()`  ?

Comment: Now it's changing to: Error: Call to protected method Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\EntityField::getFieldDefinition()